# Get object from S3 in AWS Lambda function and send to Api Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to get a .jpg file from a bucket and send it back to api gateway. I believe I have the setup correct as I see stuff being logged. It grabs the file from s3 fine, and gm is the graphicsmagick library. Not sure if I am using it right though.

In the lambda function I do this (alot of the code comes from the aws example):

```
async.waterfall([
    function download(next) {
        console.log(srcKey);
        console.log(srcBucket);
        // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
        s3.getObject({
                Bucket: srcBucket,
                Key: srcKey
            },
            next);
        },
    function transform(response, next) {
        console.log(response);
        next(null, 'image/jpeg', gm(response.Body).quality(85));

    },

    function sendData(contentType, data, next){
        console.log(contentType);
        console.log(data);
        imageBuffer = data.sourceBuffer;
        context.succeed(imageBuffer);
    }
    ]
);
```

The response header has content-length: 85948, which doesn't seem right because the original file is only 36kb. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's not unthinkable that an image could increase in size from processing, but it seems pretty unlikely.  What does the actual response body look like, say, saved then viewed in a text/hex editor?

Comment: Ha basically implemented the exact same thing, only to finally stumble upon this Q&A hours later :'(

Comment: Now it's possible - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve Get Image <-> API Gateway <-> Lambda <-> S3  integration with ease.

In lambda, instead of json, return base64 string representation of image (`buffer.toString('base64')`), force API Gateway to convert the string to binary and add specific `Content-Type` (so you don't need to use their limited binary support that enforce you to send a specific Accept header).

In AWS console, go to API Gateway, then go to the relevant method and update the settings:

- Integration Request

  - Uncheck: **Use Lambda Proxy integration**
- Method response

  - Add Response -> HTTP Status: **200**
  - Add Header: **Content-Type**
- Integration Response -> Header Mapping -> Response header -> Content-Type

  - Mapping value: **'image/jpeg'** (single quote matter)

From command line, run the command below to force convert string to binary.
First, retrieve the **rest-api-id** and the **resource-id** from API Gateway.
Then, run in CLI (replace rest-api-id and resource-id with your own):

```
aws apigateway put-integration-response --rest-api-id <rest-api-id> --resource-id <resource-id> --http-method GET --status-code 200 --content-handling CONVERT_TO_BINARY
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with Lambda Proxy integration? When I uncheck Use Lambda Proxy integration, my query strings are not passed to Lambda function anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `API Gateway` to pass back binary content when you use it with `Lambda`. `API Gateway` with `Lambda` are setup to respond with `XML/JSON` data. Read more about why and how [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-api-gateway-build-and-run-scalable-application-backends/).

Try changing your callback chain so it uploads the modified image back to `S3`. After successful upload, send back `URI` of the target object and redirect your client to it.

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that rules this out.  Can you be more specific?  The intended use of a service doesn't always preclude alternative applications and OP's application seems legitimate.  Is there an actual constraint against returning binary content through API Gateway?

Comment: To put it simply: `context.done(...)` calls `.toString()` on your buffers. `AWS Gateway` data pipeline revolves around `Integration Request/Response` and those are always JSON/XML.

Comment: Also, passing content through the API itself is a bad practice in AWS environment. Both `API Gateway` and `Lambda` have relatively short timeouts. `API Gateway` has 30s and `Lambda` 60s.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I'll look into it a little bit more, but what you say about storing the modified image back to s3 does make sense.