# AWS: downloading binaries from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to build an application that is accessible by HTTP that given a path to a document in s3 does some business logic and then returns the binary of that s3 doc.

I started doing this using API Gateway and Lambda, but ran into trouble because both services are set up to use xml or json. I started to try base64 encoding the file and Lambda and then decoded it with API Gateway, but that was not working either.

I came across this article explicitly saying not to do what I was doing [Get object from S3 in AWS Lambda function and send to Api Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213163/get-object-from-s3-in-aws-lambda-function-and-send-to-api-gateway/32214721#).

The reason I find Lambda so attractive is the instant auto scaling compared to beanstalk. Are there any alternatives to accomplish this while still providing similar scaling to Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Gateway team here - binary passthrough support is on our backlog and we hope to get that out in the near future, although I can't give a definite ETA. I agree with some of the points in the thread you linked; some of the core features in both Lambda and API Gateway are built for JSON. However we do plan to support binary passthrough so will at least be able to push the data through.

Answer (score 2):

A simple alternative is sending back a signed url.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html

```
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve({
                url: url,
                expires: expires
            });
        }
    });
```

This defers responsibility of downloading the binaries to the API consumer.